# Jest defaults to format currency to "en-US" even when the window navigator language is mocked to be "en-GB"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, format-currency

I have a test file and am testing for the `formatCurrency` function. The problem, even though I've mocked `window.navigator.language` to be `en-GB` my function in test doesn't format the currency in `£`. In the UI it works as expected, but in jest looks like you can't change `window.navigator.language`. Any suggestions?

```
const languageCurrency = {
  "en-GB": "GBP",
  "en-US": "USD",
};

const userLanguage = window.navigator.language

export const formatCurrency = (value) => 
  Intl.NumberFormat(userLanguage, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: languageCurrency[userLanguage],
  }).format(value);
```

and here is my test file

```
import { formatCurrency } from "./formatCurrency";

describe("given formatCurrency fucntion", () => {
  let windowSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get");
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    windowSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it("should set the user language to `en-GB`", () => {
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      navigator: {
        language: "en-GB",
      },
    }));

    expect(window.navigator.language).toBe("en-GB"); //this will pass
    expect(formatCurrency(1000)).toBe("£1000.00"); // this fails 
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the `userLanguage` variable is assigned in the module scope. You should **mock `window.navigator.language` first, then import the module**. So that the `userLanguage` variable will be assigned with the mock value.

Note: The code defined in the module scope will be executed immediately when you import the module.

Besides, the formatted currency should be `'£1,000.00'`

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP'}).format(1000) 
// '£1,000.00'
```

E.g.

`formatCurrency.ts`:

```
const languageCurrency = {
  'en-GB': 'GBP',
  'en-US': 'USD',
};

const userLanguage = window.navigator.language;

export const formatCurrency = (value) => {
  console.debug('languageCurrency[userLanguage]: %s userLanguage: %s', languageCurrency[userLanguage], userLanguage);
  return Intl.NumberFormat(userLanguage, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: languageCurrency[userLanguage],
  }).format(value);
};
```

`formatCurrency.test.ts`:

```
// import { formatCurrency } from './formatCurrency';

describe('given formatCurrency fucntion', () => {
  let windowSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'window', 'get');
    jest.resetModuleRegistry();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    windowSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should set the user language to `en-GB`', async () => {
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      navigator: {
        language: 'en-GB',
      },
    }));

    const { formatCurrency } = await import('./formatCurrency');

    expect(window.navigator.language).toBe('en-GB');
    expect(formatCurrency(1000)).toBe('£1,000.00');
  });

  it('should set the user language to `en-US`', async () => {
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      navigator: {
        language: 'en-US',
      },
    }));

    const { formatCurrency } = await import('./formatCurrency');

    expect(window.navigator.language).toBe('en-US');
    expect(formatCurrency(1000)).toBe('$1,000.00');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75399792/formatCurrency.test.ts (11.303 s)
  given formatCurrency fucntion
    ✓ should set the user language to `en-GB` (41 ms)
    ✓ should set the user language to `en-US` (3 ms)

  console.debug
    languageCurrency[userLanguage]: GBP userLanguage: en-GB

      at formatCurrency (stackoverflow/75399792/formatCurrency.ts:9:11)

  console.debug
    languageCurrency[userLanguage]: USD userLanguage: en-US

      at formatCurrency (stackoverflow/75399792/formatCurrency.ts:9:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.209 s
```

Comment: Hi Lin, thank you for your answer. That's great but if I add another test case to test for a different currency `en-US` and the currency to be `$1,000.00` that is failing because it is still returning currency in £. The language code seems to be set correctly to `en-US` though. Maybe the mock isn't being reset? If i test it individually it works.

Comment: @Jose Correct! Use `jest.resetModuleRegistry()` in the `beforeEach` hook. Updated answer.